# From Asia to Lat America on the cheap

Tags: budget, china, planning, mexico, routes

I'm looking for a way to get cheaply from Asia, SEA or India to Lat America: Mexico, Colombia, Dominicana, Cuba or Equador. Maybe Peru also.

- not through the US
- preferably not through Japan or Europe because even transit for me might require a visa. Although, I'm not sure yet, maybe not
- long, indirect flights - no problem
- from HK, Singapore, China or somewhere else -- doesn't matter
- my budget is around $500. The less - the better.

I've searched but haven't found anything. Your ideas?

Comment: $500 and under will be nigh impossible.  Not transiting the USA, Japan, EU, UK even more unlikely.  Basically you probably need to look flying through Australia / NZ or  China - Vancouver - Mexico City.

Comment: Ethiopian is the obvious candidate. But 500 usd will not be possible.

Comment: @MastaBaba, Ethiopian -> from where and to where?

Comment: @Jodimoro: You should check their website for destinations. It depends where you are coming from and going to. If my memory serves me well, they serve south America, but not central.

Comment: @MastaBaba where I'm going to and where I'm coming from is specified in question.

Comment: You cast a wide net in your question. Ethiopian has a decent enough website.